# React component won't re-render on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Here is my code. The imageChunks state variable is not updating correctly. Selecting an image returns an empty array. Selecting another image returns an array of the last image's base64 chunks. It seems that setImageChunks() is not triggering a re-render. What is causing this? Any help would be appreciated.

```
const [ imageChunks, setImageChunks ] = useState([])
    
const handleImageChange = async (e) => {    
            const files = e.target.files
    
            // Break image base64 string into chunks for database upload, store each in object with series (filename) and part
            const getChunks = (filename, baseStr, chunkSize) => {
                const str = baseStr.split("")
                const chunks = []
                let part = 0
                let count = str.length
                let start = 0
                while (count){
                    part++
                    start = str.length - count
                    const allowedCount = count < chunkSize ? count : chunkSize
                    chunks.push({
                        series: filename,
                        part: part,
                        data: str.slice(start, start + allowedCount).join("")
                    })
                    count -= allowedCount
                }
                
                return chunks 
            }
    
            // empty imageChunks array to prepare for new file selection
            const fileChunks = []
    
            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
                // Push file name to product object imageFiles array  
                const fileNames =  formValues.imageFiles
                fileNames.push(files[i].name)
                setFormValues({...formValues, imageFiles: fileNames})
    
                // get array of file chunk objects, push to imageChunks array
                const file = await new Response(files[i]).arrayBuffer()
                const baseString = Buffer.from(file).toString('base64')
                const chunks = getChunks(files[i].name, baseString, 10000)
    
                fileChunks.push(chunks)
            }
    
            setImageChunks(null)
            setImageChunks([...fileChunks])
            console.log(imageChunks)
        }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that when you log `imageChunks` you will see the previous state, setting state does not have an immediate effect in React. I also don't see a reason to `setImageChunks(null)`.

Comment: So it is working correctly? Maybe I could check it by console.log from a useEffect or UseCallback instead?

Comment: You can just log `imageChunks` anywhere in the body of the component's function since that log will run on every render.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for clearing that up. It was driving me crazy.